# upload video to youtube remotely using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube

I need the functionality of uploading videos to youtube using codeigniter, could anyone tell me how to do that ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This [library](https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library) does what you need. [Here](http://jimdoescode.blogspot.com/2010/10/codeigniter-and-youtube-api-this-is.html) are some author's notes for installation. The method is [well explained](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html#Browser_based_uploading) in Youtube's documentation.

Zend Framework is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this right now but I'd imagine you would use it exactly the same was as the [Youtube Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html) describes, but you would need to load it as a library through Codeigniter. Download the [standalone library](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata/) and then include that in your "libraries" folder. Then load it like normal:

```
$this->load->library('GdataLoader');
```

You will need to rename the file so that it doesn't conflict with Codeigniters Loader class. Then instantiate as normal:

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
```

Hope that helps.